# Converting XML file of CCUserDefault to JSON string

Tags: xml, json, cocos2d-x

How can I convert XML data, generated by CCUserDefault in cocos2dx, to JSON string.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert XML to JSON in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030217/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-c)

Comment: Not exactly, the main issue, is to access the xml data first from CCUserdefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to access XML content.

Simply use the following line

```
xmlData = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData(CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->getXMLFilePath().c_str(), "r", &tmpSize);
```