# Is there a way to convert JSON to XML in C++?

Tags: c++, xml, json

Do you know any existing parsers ? There seem to be some for XML to JSON, but not the other way.

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030217/how-to-convert-xml-to-json-in-c and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395072/json-xml-in-c-c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you don't find anything on google, simply take a [json](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson) [parser](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson) and write your own converter using an [xml](https://github.com/zeux/pugixml) [writer](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/).

With a dedicated data structure, such as the [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/property_tree.html), you might get both functionalities at once

example:

```
using namespace boost::property_tree;
static const std::string 
 json(""{\"my_point\":{\"name\":\"test point\",\"point\":{\"x\":1,\"y\":2,\"z\":3}}}"");

try {
  ptree pt;
  std::istringstream ss(json);
  read_json(ss, pt);
  std::ostringstream out;
  write_xml(out, pt);
  std::cout << out.str() << std::endl;
}
catch (std::exception &e) {
  std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my_point><name>test point</name><point><x>1</x><y>2</y><z>3</z></point></my_point>
```

That might be **not what you want**. If it is, consider the path sketched in the first sentence